# Entropy reversal in magnets

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, magnetic-fields, entropy, dipole

Entropy is an irreversible phenomenon without any energy supplied to reverse it.
I was reading about paramagnetic substances and how dipoles align inside them on application of magnetic field.
My question is that if a ferromagnetic substance(Having an inherent magnetic field) is used to magnetize a paramagnetic material, where is the energy expended,and where has it come from(The ferromagnet is lowering the randomness of the misaligned dipoles while it's magnetic nature itself is not spent) ? Or can we quote this as an exception?
Also ferromagnets have self alignment properties i.e an aligned dipole will align other surrounding dipoles. Here,where does the energy come from to reverse Entropy?

Comment: Energy comes from work done by you to move ferromagnate on paramagnetic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a magnet magnetises a non magnetic material, it may be said that the entropy within the non-magnetic body in question is decreasing, but on a whole, the system is getting more disordered as this is a spontaneous process and the magnetic dipoles of the magnet are getting non-aligned with evolution of negligible amounts of heat.

Answer (score 1):

To start with the law of increasing entropy applies to isolated systems.

The system you describe is isolated if one considers the total entropy of both the paramagnetic material and the permanent magnet, including any radiation. The order introduced in the paramagnetic material is balanced by a disorder in the permanent magnet  plus any radiation from changing fields. Which brings to the second part, where the energy comes from.

In permanent magnets the [domains of dipoles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_domain#Why_domains_form) have been oriented by storing a lot of energy, as

> A large region of ferromagnetic material with a constant magnetization throughout will create a large magnetic field extending into the space outside itself .This requires a lot of magnetostatic energy stored in the field.

Part of this energy is expended in orienting the dipoles in the paramagnetic material in your thought experiment, i.e. the permanent magnet suffers some disorder in its domains.